# trying to get data from text file to insert into database

Tags: python, django

I am got stuck to read data from text file which I want to insert into database.
here's my models.py file ..the text file is saved in static folder.
settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static_cdn')
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
```

urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
models.py:
from django.db import models
import os
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, title,author):
        obj = cls(title=title,author=author)

        # do something with the book
        return obj

file=open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'/static/product.txt','r'))
line=file.readline()
for lines in line:
    split_line=lines.split("|")
    a=split_line[0]
    b=split_line[1]
    obj=Book.create(a,b)
    obj.save()
```

please help me ..thanks in advance

Comment: What's the actual issue you're having? Is your intention to read the first line only?

Comment: yes, file not found error has been thrown when I try to run

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `)` after the `'/static/product.txt'`, so the overall address will be:

```
<BASE_DIR>/static/product.txt/r
```

(the `os.path.join` accept any number of arguments)

Simply change it as:

```
file = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'static/product.txt'), 'r')
```

It should work if your file is located at `<BASE_DIR>/static/product.txt`

Comment: @NagarjunaBathula Try printing the value of `os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'static/product.txt')` and compare that with your file's location.